# QML Tumbler Displacement

Tags: qt, qml

Within the documentation for the Qt QML Tumbler Element in Qt 5.15 (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html#displacement-attached-prop) the displacement property `Tumbler.displacement` is described as:

> This attached property holds a value from -visibleItemCount / 2 to
> visibleItemCount / 2

However, when I print `Tumbler.displacement` within my delegate component I get values that are larger/smaller than `visibleItemCount/2` . Does everyone experience the same?

In addition, the documentation is strange here as well. Because the following example is said to

> the item below will be 40% opaque when it is not the current item, and
> transition to 100% opacity when it becomes the current item

And the JS looks as:

```
0.4 + Math.max(0, 1 - Math.abs(Tumbler.displacement)) * 0.6
```

Based on the text before the example, I'd have expected:

```
0.4 + Math.max(0, 1 - Math.abs(Tumbler.displacement)/(visibleItemCount/2.0)) * 0.6
```

Do you agree?

I came across all these, when I was facing the issue, that all delegates were printed on the same location fully overlapping each other. Somehow Qt is not able to place the items correctly (using Qt 5.15.2 and Quick Controls 2.15).

Comment: Maybe it should, however it is not necessary.
The result in this sample is always between `0.4` and `1.0`.

Comment: @SMR ok agree, it really holds what it promises in the text before, but very vague and there is no smooth transition. Smooth transition and correct placement is what I'm interested in. But above example does not work out for me in reality.

Comment: You are right, some of the Qt sample codes on [doc.qt.io](https://doc.qt.io) are not best practice and could be replaced with a better version. For example, in this [part](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-tooltip), it is encouraged to change the hole background item rather than simply changing the [color palette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-palette.html).

Comment: We somehow found the reason for the overlapping of the elements. Apparently the Tumbler element has some issues dealing with binded width/height properties on the delegate element. As we were having a text element there, we were safe to delete it, which resolved the issue.